# Ruby on Rails/Devise - How can I pass a variable from Registrations#Create to the Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, actionmailer, super

I'd like to pass session data from my Registrations controller to my custom mailer, which is triggered in the `create` action. I'm able to do this using a global variable, but would greatly prefer not to go that route. The data I'd like to pass is stored in the `welcome_email_token` variable.

### registrations_controller.rb:

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

    def create
      client_with_valid_email_token = Client.registerable_email_token(session[:email_token])

      if client_with_valid_email_token.first.present?
        welcome_email_token = client_with_valid_email_token.first.email_token
        super
      end
    end

    protected

    def configure_sign_up_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
    end

  end
end
```

### custom_mailer.rb:

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    client = Client.find_by(email_token: welcome_email_token)
    @first_name = client.first_name
    super
  end
end
```

The code as written returns `nil` for `user`, leading `user.first_name` to throw an error. Is there a way I can pass this information to the mailer without using a global variable?

Comment: Isn't there an error in your code? Shouldn't the first line be: `user = Client.find_by(email_token: token)`

Comment: @bo-oz I'm not sure exactly what `token` represents, but it doesn't find me the client I'm looking for. `welcome_email_token` is the registration token that links to the client.

Comment: But that token / variable is not passed to the mailer method. So my point is, the query to the user is using an empty variable.

Comment: That's essentially correct. As it's written, `welcome_email_token` is empty when called in the mailer. Only if I define/call `$welcome_email_token` does it work as intended. But I want to avoid using a global variable.

Comment: So you will never find a client right? There’s already a token in de parameters of the function, so my suggestion (to avoid a global var) is to use that to find the user.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the record you are looking for, is already passed as the first parameter of this method. If you are changing so little to the method, why just go with the standard method already provided by Devise?

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    @user = record
    super
  end
end
```

The `super` is basically also calling the original confirmation_instructions method from Devise, which is:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
end
```

That uses a helper method called devise email:

```
# Configure default email options
def devise_mail(record, action, opts = {}, &block)
  initialize_from_record(record)
  mail headers_for(action, opts), &block
end
```

So I don't really see what you are trying to achieve in your method, that's not already handled by Devise.

Comment: Thank you for this, and unpacking Devise a bit for me. While `@user = record` is accurate, what I really need is `client`'s first name, which `record` doesn't have. I've edited my code to be a little more clear (I changed the local `user` to `client`.)

Comment: Call it what you like, but record contains reference to whatever model you use for your ‘user’, whether you name it client or member or whatever doesn’t matter. Have you tried ‘record.first_name’?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. The thing is, my program has a `client` in existence already. Sometimes a `client` chooses to sign up as a `user`. So when I'm creating a user, I need to reference the client to get their first name - but the association doesn't occur until after Devise sends the confirmation email. I ended up "solving" this by canceling Devise's auto-sending of the confirmation email, and sending it after that association has been made. I'd still be interested in learning a true solution for this problem. Thank you for your help, @bo-oz!

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like a design error. Why would you need a separate Client model? Couldn't that be a role, or a simple flag within the User model? When are you collecting the Client record, and in what workflow, due to what action will it become a record in the User model? I think these things are fundamental to truly understand the issue at hand and determine how it should/can be solved.

Comment: You may be right that it could've been set up better. I'm not sure. I just came into the codebase. The client is created by another website and sent directly to us. So it exists before we do anything with it. Then some of those clients eventually sign up as users on our site.

Comment: And what enables you to tie a registration to an existing customer? They might sign-up with a different e-mail, so you never know for sure right? Or is there some unique identifier?

Comment: Yes, the email_token.

Comment: So the email token is already stored in the Client model... how is it provided when creating a new User? It is not the same as the Devise e-mail token right?

Comment: That's correct, the Devise token is the confirmation token after the User is created. The `email_token` is a param in the user sign-up page url, but it's not passed to the user when it's created. I considered that as an option, but we didn't want to store it in the users table just for this one-time use. That's why I was hoping there'd be a way to pass it from the controller to the mailer.